# How to I convert a local Tampermonkey script to web-based for purposes of synchronization?

Tags: google-chrome, tampermonkey

I want my TM scripts to sync and I read in the FAQ that is possible, but [it gives the caveat](https://tampermonkey.net/faq.php?ext=dhdg&show=dhdg#Q105):

> Tampermonkey can only sync scripts that are installed from a remote source. This source can be any URL that is accessible by both of your Chrome browsers.

Ok, cool, I have a web server I can host it at but the problem becomes that I cannot figure out how one does this.

- What do I name the file for the script on the webserver, I assume it has some standard...?
- How do I load a script from a webserver then?
  When I hit the + to add a new script it takes me to the local script creation interface, I do not see where one would plug in a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Save your script as a `*.user.js` file. EG: `AddUnicornIconsToTwitter.user.js`.
2. Make sure your script has a [`@version` directive](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_version).  This is how Tampermonkey will know when a script needs to be updated.
3. Upload that file to a web-accessible folder on your sever. EG:
   `YOUR_SERVER.COM/myTMscripts/`
4. To install, merely browse to that new address using Chrome, EG:
   `https://YOUR_SERVER.COM/myTMscripts/AddUnicornIconsToTwitter.user.js`
5. Follow the Tampermonkey prompts to install the script.
6. If you change the script, be sure to increment the `@version` number